# T-SQL average rounded to the closest integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not sure if this has been asked before, but how do I get the average rounded to the closest integer in T-SQL?

Comment: Floor will always round down.

Comment: @David, thanks for hint. I didn't see, that he wants the *closest* integer, I thought it should be rounded down. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked for it:

```
CONVERT(int,ROUND(AVG(CAST(COLUMN-NAME AS DECIMAL)) ,0))
```

Isn't there a shorter way of doing it though?

Comment: What is the name and data type of the column you are trying to average?

Comment: datatype is integer - name is rating

Comment: See results below.  It looks like your innermost cast to decimal does make a difference. You can use CAST or CONVERT, I wouldn't mix them though just for neatness.

Answer (score 18):

This should do it. You might need a GROUP BY on the End depending on what you are looking for the average of.

```
SELECT CONVERT(int,ROUND(AVG(ColumnName),0))
FROM 
TableName
```

EDIT:  This question is more interesting than I first thought.

If we set up a dummy table like so...

```
WITH CTE

AS

(
    SELECT 3 AS Rating
    UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 7
)


SELECT AVG(Rating)
FROM 
CTE
```

We get an integer average of 4

However if we do this

```
WITH CTE

AS

(
    SELECT 3.0 AS Rating
    UNION SELECT 4.0
    UNION SELECT 7.0
)


SELECT AVG(Rating)
FROM 
CTE
```

We get a decimal average of 4.666..etc

So it looks like the way to go is

```
WITH CTE

AS

(
    SELECT 3 AS Rating
    UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 7
)
SELECT CONVERT(int,ROUND(AVG(CONVERT(decimal,Rating)),0))
FROM CTE
```

Which will return an integer value of 5 which is what you are looking for.

Comment: Did you replace both columnname and tablename with real names?

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I have to admit to be a little surprised by this result.  It makes sense but it isn't what I expected.

Answer (score 13):

If you are in SQL Server, just use `round(avg(column * 1.0), 0)`.

The reason for `* 1.0` is because sql server in some cases returns calculations using the same datatype of the values used in the calculation. So, if you calculate the average of 3, 4 and 4, the result is 3.66..., but the datatype of the result is integer, therefore the sql server will truncate 3.66... to 3, using `* 1.0` implicit convert the input to a decimal.

Alternatively, you can convert or cast the values before the average calculation, like `cast(column as decimal)` instead of using the `* 1.0` trick.

If your column it's not a integer column, you can remove the `* 1.0`.

PS: the result of `round(avg(column * 1.0), 0)` still is a decimal, you can explicit convert it using `convert(int, round(avg(column * 1.0), 0), 0)` or just let whatever language you are using do the job (it's a implicit conversion)

Answer (score 8):

```
Select cast(AVG(columnname) as integer)
```

Answer (score 4):

T-SQL2018.

`CAST(ROUND(COLUMN, 0) AS INT)`  This code does the job for me and gives the output I require so a 4.8 becomes 5.

whereas

`CAST(AVG(COLUMN) AS INT)`  This code almost does the job but rounds down, so 4.8 becomes a 4 and not 5.

Comment: By far the best and simplest answer. IMHO

Comment: This doesn't work for some cases, e.g.:
`select .9 as val into #x;`
`select cast(round(val, 0) as int) from #x -- error`

Answer (score 2):

```
select cast(avg(a+.5) as int) from 
    (select 1 a union all select 2) b
```

If you don't like shortcuts, you could use the long way:

```
select round(avg(cast(a as real)), 0) 
    from (select 1 a union all select 2) b
```

Answer (score 1):

The following statements are equivalent:

```
-- the original code
CONVERT(int, ROUND(AVG(CAST(mycolumn AS DECIMAL)) ,0))

-- using '1e0 * column' implicitly converts mycolumn value to float
CONVERT(int, ROUND(AVG(1e0 * mycolumn) ,0))

-- the conversion to INT already rounds the value
CONVERT(INT, AVG(1e0 * mycolumn))
```

Comment: CONVERT(INT, AVG(1e0 * mycolumn)) worked for me to simply convert to integer value!

Answer (score -2):

On SQL 2014,

```
select round(94,-1)
select round(95,-1)
```