# SQL Server custom rounding

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where :

- 24.9999 should be 25
- 24.5000 should be 25
- 24.4999 should be 24
- 24.1111 should be 24

I tried `Ceiling`, but the result will be 25, where `Floor` will be 24 for all of them.

How to accomplish this?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Note: it might be helpful to let you know that I want this functionality to be  inside a `computed column`.

Comment: Are you looking for something like - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063962/t-sql-average-rounded-to-the-closest-integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
Round(YourNumber, 0)
```

The 0 indicates the precision (i.e. number of decimal places); if you wanted to round 42.51 to 42.5, you'd replace the 0 with 1, for example.

Make sure not to use `float`s - they can sometimes be approximated, which causes values to be rounded incorrectly on occasion.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`round()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms175003.aspx) with `0` as `[length]` parameter :

```
round(field, 0)
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a01f/2)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but its not working on sql server. Even the round function have 2/3 parameters here

Comment: Should be `Round(YourNumber, 0)` to get what you want.

Comment: @aphrael OMG.. Thanks  a lot mate, please answer my question so i can accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Just now I took a look at this article:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/01ca0dd6-fe5b-4ec9-9949-ce3608fcebf6/sqlround?forum=sqlservermanagementzhcht

Sorry that it isn't english, but it said:

```
If you need to use round, try not to use float, use decimal or numeric instead
```

I tried casting the field to decimal, and it works, here's the fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a01fa/4

Here's my select statement:

```
select round(cast(smth as decimal)) from tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

`select round(cast(column as decimal)) from tbl` will work nice
But
`select round(column, 0) from tbl` will not work that nicely because in this case 24.5000 will result 24 which should be 25 in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You should use round(numeric_expression, 4) . Length 4 represents the length of precision for decimal values . In your case since the decimal values are of length 4, it will round according to 4 decimal values .

Answer (score 0):

you can proceed like this for your provide data

```
select CAST(CEILING(24.5000)AS INT)
select CAST(CEILING(24.9999)AS INT)
select CAST(CEILING(24.1111 -1)AS INT)
select CAST(CEILING(24.4999 - 1)AS INT)
```

Or you have lot of data in you table with certain conditions then you can pick the decimal values after '.' dot and write case condition accordind to that it is not way to do so but to achieve results

```
declare @t table (ID decimal(18,4))
insert into @t(ID)values (24.5000),(24.9999),(24.1111),(24.4999)
select case when RIGHT(ID, LEN(ID) - CHARINDEX ('.', ID)) - 1 > 4500
THEN CAST(CEILING(ID)AS INT)  
ELSE CAST(CEILING(ID - 1)AS INT) END from @t
```